# Run process using CMD command fails if the argument is not hardcoded

Tags: powershell, process

I want to run `cmd` command and run `process`:

This function works fins:

```
function RunProcess($processPath)
{
    &$processPath "my argument"
}
```

Usage:

```
RunProcess "myExe.exe"
```

Now if I want to make it more generic and send also the argument:

```
function RunProcess($processPath, $ar)
{
    &$processPath $ar
}
```

Usage:

```
RunProcess "myExe.exe" "my argument"
```

This failed and I don't know why.

Comment: so, I assume that `Start-Process` is to complicated to implement?

Comment: Please be more descriptive than "This failed".

Comment: it's working fine for me , I checked with : RunProcess "notepad.exe" "c:\firstScript.ps1"

Comment: You say you want to run a process in CMD, but CMD doesn't appear anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me, you could try this as well:

```
function RunProcess($processPath, $ar)
{
    Start-Process $processPath -ArgumentList $ar
}
```